# Validation(HTML5) The element i cannot be nested within the element button

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" class="subscr-next" ><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></asp:Button>
```

I have a ready scheme and I wanna convert to asp.net.But I'm taking two errors.

Firstly,Validation(HTML5) The element i cannot be nested within the element button

Second,Content is not allowed between the opening ad closing tags for element button.

I'm okey about it is not allowed content between tags.But I gotta insert icon to button

Thanks for answers

Comment: You're not using HTML 5, you're using ASP.NET webforms with the `<asp:button>` control.  You need to look into using an `<asp:ImageButton>` or just use a `<span>` with a nested `i` tag.  However, the meaning of an `i` tag has changed... http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/

Comment: I can't answer your help sorry,Thanks because I solved with your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace asp.net button with html5 button and add `runat="server"` attribute on it. This will work. For example,

```
<button id="Button2" runat="server" class="subscr-next"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
```